# GitHub: two different custom domains one for organization and one for project

Tags: github, github-pages

I have an organization foo and a project bar hosted on GitHub:

github.com/foo/bar.git

I would like a custom domain foo.org pointing on foo.github.io and bar.org pointing on the bar project page (its webpage resides in the gh-pages branch of github.com/foo/bar.git). How can I do it?

Comment: By "the bar project page", do you mean a GitHub Pages site or your repository (`github.com/foor/bar`)?

Comment: I mean GitHub Pages of the project bar which reside in the gh-pages branch of github.com/foo/bar.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [set up a custom domain with GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) for each of your two GitHub Pages repos (named `foo.github.io` and `bar`). Make sure that the CNAME file in `foo.github.io` points to `foo.org`, and that the CNAME in `bar` points to `bar.org`.

Comment: And what about the DNS CNAME entries for foo.org and bar.org? Both of them will point on foo.github.io?

Comment: Yes. See [Tips for configuring a CNAME record with your DNS provider](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-a-cname-record-with-your-dns-provider/) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the company where you are hosting your domains supports redirecting. Otherwise you should buy some cheap hosting, and put this code on the index.php of this domain.

```php
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: This probably isn't necessary, GitHub has built in support for custom domains (see [Setting up a custom domain with GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/)).

Comment: It is when he wants to link to the repository.